# Huge performance drop after moving to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, performance, azure, azure-web-app-service

**Currently we were working on a cloud migration project where we made the following changes:**

- SQL Server 2014 to Azure SQL PaaS
- Redis cache[Windows porting] to Azure Redis PaaS
- Static files from shared drives to Azure File Service
- Implemented Transient Fault Handling for database interactions.
- HttpSessionState changed from SQL Server to Custom[Redis PaaS]

**The Application had two web applications that use the same database:**

- One built in Classic model of dot net coding with web-forms.
- The other application built using dot net MVC4.

**After we moved the applications from existing Rackspace environment[2 servers each with 4GB RAM] to Azure and ran a load test and received the following results:**

- The MVC4 application is fractionally faster.
- The Web-Form application started performing poorly, with same load,
  response time increased from 0.46 seconds to 45.8 seconds.

The memory usage is same, database utilization is around 30%-40% and the **CPU utilization in nearly 100%(all the web-servers) at 1100 concurrent users(at Rackspace, it served 4500 concurrent users).**

We tested the application **2 D5 azure server VMs** with RAM being higher and CPU being faster.

Can anyone highlight how such drastic performance drop(one application performing almost same, other one performing almost 100 times slower) is possible?

**NB:** One observation, the CPU utilization stays at 100% even after 30mins of stopping the load-test. Then it drops quickly.

Comment: Profile the app under load to find what's taking so much CPU. You can do that by using PerfView.

Comment: @usr : We did so using ServiceProfiler, not conclusive. I am looking for any pointers why the same code that runs without an issue in one environment can perform so poor in a server with better configurations. If you mean the application having leakage, how come it perform better in the other env.??

Comment: @SamGhatak: both environments are so different that you cannot comparte them. Even more than that, you do not have control over the Azure environment so all you can do are assumptions and guesses. I think that you really need to profile the app to gather valid information.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia ,We understand that and we are doing the same. We are shifted in IaaS model from our on - premise model. We just want to know that is it normal behavior that if an application is being lift and shifted from on-premise (servers are VMs) to Azure IaaS model, this kind of odd behavior could appear.

Comment: There could be `if (azure) while (true);`. Same code, different perf. That's why you need to profile to find the location of the behavior difference. Why is the result "inconclusive"? Let's work on that to make it conclusive.

Comment: @usr : Am afraid there is no such `if (azure)` part actually, moreover, first we thought the same and ran the updated code in a load test in on-premises env...it performed good as before, its not conclusive till now, we are still working on it :) ...only reason we think it might me something else because the same code performs well outside azure....

Comment: As I explained: Same code but dependent on environment somehow. Closing this now because no answer is possible without the profile or at least an indication of what code is wrong. What do you mean by inconclusive?

Answer (score 1):

I will second the notion (emphatically) that you invest as much time and energy as you can in profiling your application to identify bottlenecks. Run profiles on-premises and in Azure and compare, if possible.

Your application clearly has many moving parts and a reasonably large surface area... that's no crime, but it does mean that its hard to pinpoint the issue(s) you're having without some visibility into runtime behavior. The issue could lie in your Redis caching, in the static file handling, or in the session state loading/unloading/interaction cycle. Or it could be elsewhere. There's no magic answer here... you need data.

That said... I've consulted on several Azure migration projects and my experience tells me that one area to look closer at is the interaction between your ASP.NET Web Forms code and SQL. Overly-chatty applications (ones that average multiple SQL calls per HTTP request) and/or ones that issue expensive queries that perform lots of logic on the database or return large result sets, tend to exhibit poor performance in public clouds like Azure, where code and data may not be co-located, "noisy neighbor" problems can impact database performance, etc. These issues aren't unique to Web Forms applications or Azure, but they tend to be exacerbated in older, legacy applications that were written with an assumption of code and data being physically close. Since you don't control (completely) where your code and data live in Azure relative to each other, issues that may be masked in an on-prem scenario can surface when moving to the cloud.

Some specifics to consider:

1. take a close look at the use of data binding in your Web Forms app... in practice it tends to encourage expensive queries and transfer of large result sets from database to application, something you might sometimes get away with on-premises but not in the cloud
2. take another look at your SQL configuration... you don't mention what tier you're using (Basic, Standard, Premium) but this choice can have a big impact on your overall app performance (and budget!). If it turns out (for example) that your Web Forms app does issue expensive queries, then use of a higher tier may help

[Azure SQL DB tiers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/)

3. familiarize yourself with the notion of "cloud native" vs. "cloud capable" applications... generally speaking, just because you can find a way to run an application in the cloud doesn't mean its ideally suited to do so. From your description it sounds like you've made some effort to utilize some cloud-native services, so that's a good start. But if I had to guess (since we can't see your code) I'd think that you might need some additional refactoring in your Web Forms app to make it more efficient and better able to run in an environment you don't have 100% control over.

[More on cloud-native](http://thenewstack.io/best-practices-for-developing-cloud-native-applications-and-microservice-architectures/)

[dated but still relevant advice on Azure migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728592.aspx)

If you can give us more details on where you see bottlenecks, we can offer more specific advice.

Best of luck!

Comment: thanks @JoshL,  its really informative...I understand its not something that can be solved by simple workarounds. Throughout investigation and remediation might be required.. and we are doing the same right now.. . but to be specific I wanted to know if this a common behavior... we were using P3 database...will update the qns with data pointers as much as possible...+1 from me

Answer (score 0):

There is some loop in the code that cause 100% CPU.

When the problem occurs, take a dump from (the kudu). Analyze it in windbg by 
1) list threads cpu time with !runaway
2) check the callstack of the threads, specifically the greatest cpu consumer with
 ~*e!clrstack  and with ~*kb